# Setting Customer url scheme in Cordova 3.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to set a custom url scheme in my Cordova application. Not sure why its not working.

```
<key>CFBundleURLName</key>
<string>com.myproject.myapp</string>
```

I am setting this in my main config.xml, is this correct? Or am I going in the wrong direction.

Any help would be lovely.

Update:

So now i have tried doing this

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.myproject.myapp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myappresume</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

After reading alot of documentation, i believe it should be this.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of playing around and getting confused with documentation.

It turns out that Cordova apps do have a plist (I thought the plist was now the config.xml). This is located in the resources folder and called something like myapp.plist. I added the below code and it worked fine.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.myproject.myapp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myappresume</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```